# How does TComboBoxEx in VCL work to add images in it?

Tags: delphi, combobox, vcl, tcombobox

I'm trying to add images into a combobox instead of text. Someone recommended I use the `TComboBoxEx` instead of `TComboBox`, but how does it work?

I found a tutorial, but it's confusing and I do not understand. Does it work different than normal ComboBox? https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Alexandria/en/TComboBoxEx_(Delphi)

With `TComboBox`, there's a `TStrings` `Items` property that I can use to change the text.

I do not see a `Items` property for `TComboBoxEx`.

How can I have images for a dropdown instead of Text?

Comment: Use the `ItemsEx` property.

Comment: The answer is found in the kink you provided if you read the code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The code doesn't make sense or help. It is just confusing

Comment: I think it makes sense

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are not a beginner like me

Comment: If you'd read it, it tells you about the image list, how to connect it to the control, and how to add items with image indices. It looks like you didn't stick with it. That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ItemsEx` property to add text and images. Double clicking on `ItemsEx` opens this window:

[image: Delphi Edit ComboBoxEx ItemsEx]

From there with the top-left button, you can add dropdown items and then you'll see a `Caption` and `ImageIndex` for each item:

[image: Delphi Edit ComboBoxEx ItemsEx]

The images are populated through a `TImageList` component that you have to drop onto the form as well and then there's an `Images` property on the `TComboBoxEx` that you have to set equal to the `TImageList`

And that's it. Then you have your ComboBox with images:

[image: Delphi TComboBoxEx]